# Is there a SCP alternative for PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, scp

I need to write a script that transfers files from a folder onto another server (Linux), but the script that's transferring files is on windows, and I was wondering if there was an alternative to `scp` for PowerShell (or if there was another way of doing this)

Comment: For anyone that is using PowerShell version 3 or later, https://github.com/darkoperator/Posh-SSH is an option.

Comment: honestly its freaking ridiculous this task is so hard in MS still. This is the very basic task of server administrating..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`pscp.exe` is a viable option, but I have been using a library from [Rebex](http://www.rebex.net/) for a couple years now for SFTP and FTPS transfers in both C# apps and PowerShell scripts with great success. Their package also includes [an SCP object](http://www.rebex.net/sftp.net/features/scp.aspx) but I haven't personally used it.

It does cost money vs. `pscp` being free. Before selecting the Rebex package, I had considered going the PuTTY route but my team decided that having a library we could easily roll into any app/script was worthwhile in the long term.

Comment: If you have the budget for it, yes :-)

Comment: This blog post can help you with getting Rebex SFTP running in PowerShell http://blog.rebex.net/news/archive/2008/09/25/how-to-use-FTP-or-SFTP-in-PowerShell.aspx

Answer (score 23):

There is a handy little tool that comes with [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) called `pscp.exe` that will do this and can be called in powershell easily.

Example below copies from windows to a CentOS box (logging in as the usercode "bill") and you use the `-pw` switch in `pscp` to pass in a password (otherwise the command window that is spawned will prompt for the Linux password):

```
Start-Process 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\pscp.exe' -ArgumentList ("-scp -pw password C:\Document.rtf bill@192.168.0.28:/home/bill/")
```

```
PuTTY Secure Copy client
Release 0.62
Usage: pscp [options] [user@]host:source target
       pscp [options] source [source...] [user@]host:target
       pscp [options] -ls [user@]host:filespec
Options:
  -V        print version information and exit
  -pgpfp    print PGP key fingerprints and exit
  -p        preserve file attributes
  -q        quiet, don't show statistics
  -r        copy directories recursively
  -v        show verbose messages
  -load sessname  Load settings from saved session
  -P port   connect to specified port
  -l user   connect with specified username
  -pw passw login with specified password
  -1 -2     force use of particular SSH protocol version
  -4 -6     force use of IPv4 or IPv6
  -C        enable compression
  -i key    private key file for authentication
  -noagent  disable use of Pageant
  -agent    enable use of Pageant
  -batch    disable all interactive prompts
  -unsafe   allow server-side wildcards (DANGEROUS)
  -sftp     force use of SFTP protocol
  -scp      force use of SCP protocol
```

Comment: Use key based auth instead of putting the password in your script.

Comment: Fair point, this was just a quick example to show that PSCP could do the job requested :-)

Comment: Windows noob here.  When I do this, I just get a blank console window that disappears after about 10 seconds, and the SCP transfer does not appear to have occurred. Any ideas as to what might be going on?

Comment: I was able to figure out that there was a firewall issue by running the command from Command Prompt instead of Powershell, but it would be nice if there were some way of getting output from running the command in Powershell :)

Comment: @jayhendren from the doc at https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter5.html - pscp returns an error code. So immediately after the started process completes, check the value of $lastexitcode or put the result of your start-process statement into a variable then check that - e.g $result = Start-Process

Comment: @jayhendren $result=start-process ‘C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\pscp.exe’ -argumentlist ...

Comment: @jayhendren you could also try the -v switch in your pscp argumentlist and also the -sshlog <logfile path> option - it is available in plink.exe so May be in pscp also

Answer (score 6):

You can use [WinSCP .NET assembly](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) from [PowerShell](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell) for SCP transfers.

For example see http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell#example

The example uses SFTP protocol. To use SCP, just modify it to:

```
$sessionOptions.Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Scp
```

Though if your server support SCP protocol, it's likely it also supports SFTP. SFTP is better choice, if you have the option.

Answer (score 5):

## Why use an alternative to SCP when you can use SCP?

Windows has OpenSSH (which includes SCP) as an optional component these days, so you could just use that. It first appeared in the Autumn 2018 version of Windows 10. It's nearly identical to the command you find in most Linux distributions, as it's derived from the same code base. Microsoft just made one or two minor tweaks to make it work on windows.

It is simple to install just go to **Start->Settings->Apps->Optional Features->View Features** enter in OpenSSH in the search box and check the OpenSSH client and click next. See [OpenSSH in Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_overview) for more detailed instructions on how to set it up. For a more PowerShell way of installing it run this from an elevated PowerShell prompt:

```
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0
```

You can use this command to check if there is a newer version and whether you already have it installed:

```
Get-WindowsCapability -Online | Where Name -Like '*ssh*'
```

Once installed, you call `scp` from PowerShell just like you would any other executable command.

```
scp file.dat user.name@example.com:/target/path
```

### If you really don't want to use SCP use Copy-Item

This requires PowerShell to be installed on your server. Yes you can install PowerShell on Linux. Just call Copy-Item with the `-ToSession` parameter passed an SSH connected session, I've never actually tried it though. It requires a recent version of PowerShell and some setting up see [PowerShell remoting over SSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ssh-remoting-in-powershell-core?view=powershell-7). Something like this:

```
Copy-Item C:\localPath\*.* ~\remotePath\ -ToSession (New-PSSession -HostName UserA@LinuxServer01:22 -KeyFilePath c:\\userAKey_rsa)
```

If both machines are Windows machines you can use the same `-ToSession` parameter to copy files over WinRM. But both machines have to be domain joined or there is the possibility of security issues.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a ".NET friendly" way:

you can use the [SharpSSH](http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpSSH.aspx) dll to execute ssh commands, and do scp/sftp tranfers.

For example:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom((Resolve-Path .\Tamir.SharpSSH.dll))

$ssh = New-Object Tamir.SharpSsh.Sftp("server","user","password")

$ssh.Connect()

$ssh.Put("C:\localfile","distantfile")

$ssh.Close()
```

There is the [SSH.Net](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET) library, too, it does approximatively the same things.