# Debugging file transfer using pscp executed from PowerShell

Tags: linux, powershell, putty, scp, pscp

I am trying to use PowerShell to send a file from a Windows 10 dev box to a CentOS 7 server across a local area network.

When I run the following command from PowerShell in the Windows 10 dev box, Putty opens, but then closes before asking for password.  And then the test file (`index.html`) is not present in the intended destination folder on the CentOS 7 server.

```
Start-Process 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\pscp.exe' -ArgumentList ("-scp -pw password C:\projects\temp\junk\index.html some_user_name@192.168.1.5:/home/some_user_name/")
```

**How can I diagnose what problem is causing this command to fail?  And what specific steps need to be taken in order for the file to be successfully transferred from the devbox to the server?**

I have double checked the obvious things, like the file paths, the user name, and the IP.

The above command is derived from this suggestion by [@GrahamGold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18344004/is-there-a-scp-alternative-for-powershell#18346396).

Comment: pscp.exe being the gui client? ;) offtopic, why do you have the args in ()?

Comment: @JaquelineVanek [it seems](https://superuser.com/questions/532919/how-to-use-pscp-to-copy-file-from-unix-machine-to-windows-machine-where-target-p) pscp works in command line. I'm also wondering about the parens :). Edit: the link I provided explains you could also use the .NET assembly for WinSCP.

Comment: You don't need any of the boilerplate Start-Process stuff; `pscp -scp -pw pass c:\folder\file.txt username@servername:~/` transfers fine for me, from the powershell prompt... does your password have $ symbols in it? You use double quotes, so you need to escape PowerShell special characters inside it..

Comment: @sodawillow Please see link to source of the code, which I just added to the end of the OP.

Comment: "and you use the -pw switch in pscp to pass in a password" so, why do you expect putty asking for a pass?

Comment: Any reason you use `Start-Process`? Why don't you use simply `& "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\pscp.exe" -scp ...`? - Did you test the same command on command-line? What does it do? `"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\pscp.exe" -scp -pw password C:\projects\temp\junk\index.html some_user_name@192.168.1.5:/home/some_user_name/"`

Comment: why even powershell for that matter?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Your answer works.  If you want to write it up as an answer, I would be happy to mark it as accepted and +1.  I think that the community would greatly appreciate if you invested a little time explaining the concepts behind how it works and why.

Comment: guess we can remove the powershell tag now? ;)

Comment: @CodeMed It actually does not make sense, that it *just works* by removing the `Start-Process`, leaving other things the same - Your code is correct as such.

Comment: @JaquelineVanek Unless you can show how to make it work with PowerShell.  See the link at the end of the OP to the source of this approach.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl The code that works on my devbox is `pscp -scp -pw pass C:\projects\temp\junk\index.html some_user_name@192.168.1.5:~/`.  Does this still not make sense?

Comment: @CodeMed I don't know what the concept is, I just wrote the command without the fluff and it worked. I don't know why GrahamGold wrapped it in Start-Process or why Start-Process didn't work for you, or how your version of pscp launched a GUI - do you use the Putty Agent in your systray?

Comment: @CodeMed Maybe you have 64-bit version of PuTTY/pscp installed? So the path is `C:\Program Files` and not `C:\Program Files (x86)`? - Or the `/home/some_user_name/` path is wrong.

Comment: As I've suggested you above, try `"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\pscp.exe" -scp -pw password C:\projects\temp\junk\index.html some_user_name@192.168.1.5:/home/some_user_name/` on `cmd.exe` console, and you will see what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In general, there's nothing wrong with your command. It should work (if all arguments are correct).

---

To diagnose the problem, first test the command on Windows command-line (`cmd.exe`):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\pscp.exe" -scp -pw password C:\projects\temp\junk\index.html some_user_name@192.168.1.5:/home/some_user_name/
```

This way, the output is preserved and you will see, what went wrong (if anything).

The next step is to do the same in PowerShell script using call operator `&` (though the result should be the same):

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\pscp.exe" -scp -pw password C:\projects\temp\junk\index.html some_user_name@192.168.1.5:/home/some_user_name/
```

---

If that works, it's time to replace `&` with the `Start-Process` cmdlet, if you really want that. But in general, I do not see a point of that, unless you want to run the transfer asynchronously.

---

Though if you want to make you command portable, you need to add [`-hostkey` switch](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-hostkey).

See my answer to [Using echo y as an automated response to a pcp hostkey prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39924091/850848).