# Copying python scripts from local to remote mahcine

Tags: python-3.x, powershell

I have two computers, both windows 64-bit machines. Call the local computer machine A and the remote computer machine B. I have a `script.py` file on machine A. Without leaving machine A, I want to:

1. Copy `script.py` onto machine B;
2. Run `script.py` on machine B;
3. Get the output on machine A.

I'm having problems with step 1.

Steps 2. and 3. are solved already.

I've configured both computers so that I can successfully run from PowerShell6 Invoke-Commands. The PSSessions established between machine A and B are functional. I can successfully run a `script.py` that is on machine B from machine A:

```
Enter-PSSession -hostname $hostname -username pshell 
-ScriptBlock{c:\Users\pshell\Anaconda3\python.exe script.py};
```

and get the output back to machine A. 
However, I don't know find the commands to copy `script.py` from machine A to machine B. I think it's a relatively easy task but I can't find the relevant commands.  Any indications/suggestions not including third-party software/packages are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

From [Is there a SCP alternative for PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18344004/is-there-a-scp-alternative-for-powershell): the little tool `pscp.py`, which comes with Putty can solve your task 1.

For an example with PowerShell see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18346396).

Answer (score 0):

Copy-Item -Path "ENTER_PATH HERE" -Destination "ENTER_PATH_HERE" -Recurse